# Not getting email notifications on answers and comments

Tags: support, bug, email, email-notification

I have read many people that wrote about this but nothing helped so far. I never get any email notification about answers or comments to my questions although my settings are set up to receive them. What am I missing?

Comment: Stupid question, but I have to ask - have you entered the right e-mail address? Have you checked your spam folder? Your spam filter might be classifying them as spam.

Comment: If you checked your inbox on-site, then there's nothing to email you. We don't send immediate email notifications, ever. You're currently set up to receive unread notifications every three hours, and haven't been sent such an email since August 31.

Comment: @Chris, stupid comment but I'll answer anyway. Yes, correct email and checked spam and filters.
@ animuson, take this post for example. I asked it on Nov 12 and only came back here now to check it. Hadn't got any emails about it. So the issue still exists.